# Limitation of continuity equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, bernoulli-equation

Why continuity equation is not used in deriving/ finding the velocity for pitot tube where as both Continuity and Bernoulli's equation is used for deriving/ finding the velocity at throat in Venturimetre?

Comment: Continuity equation is continuous, meaning that you can get velocity at a throat with continuously varying thickness. For the pitot tube, however, simple mass conservation will work - this is basically continuity in a different form.

Comment: For a pitot tube, the continuity equation is not needed because the velocity at the entrance to the pitot tube is known, namely zero.